# error installing ruby in docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, jenkins, cicd

I am trying to add rvm/ruby 3.1.2 to a docker container to be used in a pipeline.
I believe this used to work, but now I am getting the following error:

```
[2023-09-19T14:06:31.918Z] ruby-3.0.0 - #extracting ruby-3.0.0 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-3.0.0.....
[2023-09-19T14:06:58.427Z] ruby-3.0.0 - #configuring.........................................................................
[2023-09-19T14:06:58.427Z] ruby-3.0.0 - #post-configuration..
[2023-09-19T14:07:54.730Z] ruby-3.0.0 - #compiling..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
[2023-09-19T14:07:54.730Z] Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
[2023-09-19T14:07:54.730Z] please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1695132378_ruby-3.0.0/make.log
[2023-09-19T14:07:54.730Z] 
[2023-09-19T14:07:54.730Z] There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
[2023-09-19T14:07:54.730Z] The command '/bin/bash -c -l curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -     && curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby     && source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm     && rvm install 3.2.1' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I am not sure how to fix it.

```bash
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:latest

USER root
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "-l"]

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    gnupg \
    procps

#install ruby3
RUN curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import - \
    && curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby \
    && source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm \
    && rvm install 3.2.1
```

Comment: The output you have pasted does not match your Dockerfile. In the Dockerfile, you try to install Ruby 3.2.1 while your error output indicates that you attempt to install Ruby 3.0.0. Make sure that you are using the correct docker image. In any case: using Ruby 3.0 won't work with your docker image since its base OS it only ships with OpenSSL 3.0 which is only compatible with Ruby >= 3.1.

Comment: Can you directly use the `ruby:3.1.2` image, maybe in combination with a Jenkinsfile [`agent`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#execution-environment) block telling the specific pipeline stage to run in a container?

Comment: the output is definitely strange that it doesn't match 3.0.0 vs 3.2.1 specified.  but that is def what is happening.  Looking into it more.